# VSTO 2010 excel addins cannot be loaded on target xp machine

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010

I published my excel addins with clickonce on vs2010.
It`s prerequisites contains .net framework 4 client,vsto 2010 and installer3.5.

Deploying it on win7 works well,when I deploy it on xp,installing no error occured,
but it(com) cannot loaded when run excel app.

I tried mang mehods,only when I manually installed .net framework 2.0 or 3.0 or 3.5 
my addin will appear

I donot know why.

thanks

Comment: what version of Excel is it being used on?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dumb question, when deploying are your users installing the .vsto or the setup.exe (aka bootstrap). If they are installing the just the .vsto file they aren't getting any of the pre-reqs. They live in the setup.exe. Also are you installing the PIAs (or are you using the embedded PIAs which is new to 2010)? Win7 machines tend to have the right pre-reqs but when you go back in time on XP they don't.